# Testing if a method is being called inside of another method if conditions are true in C# using Moq framework

Tags: c#, .net, testing, nunit, moq

Hope someone can help me with this issue. I am writing a test which will check if when method `Start()` is called, will a method `StartProcOld` or `StartProcNew` will be invoked. They are each wrapped around an if statement which will check if a condition(flag) is met and according to that run one of these methods. My issue is that the test keeps failing and even though when I debug I can see the actual correct method being called for the condition, the test fails and says it was invoked 0 times. Here is the test code I have that checks if `StartProcOld` is called. Thank you.

```
[TestFixture]
    public class SomeTests
    {
        private Mock<BringClass> _BringClassMock;
        private NameValueCollection _mainC;
        private ClassWhereStartSitsIn.ClassWhereStartSitsIn _plugin;
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            _BringClassMock = new Mock<BringClass>();
            _mainC= new NameValueCollection();
            _plugin = new ClassWhereStartSitsIn.ClassWhereStartSitsIn();
            _pluginMock = new Mock<ClassWhereStartSitsIn.ClassWhereStartSitsIn>();
            _mockInterface = new Mock<IBringPlugIn>()
        }
        [Test]
        public void StartProcOldIsCalled()
        {
            _mainC.Add("Flag", "FALSE");
           _BringClassMock.Setup(x => x. StartProcOld(some params).CallBack<type of params>(()) => new NameValueCollection());
            _plugin.Start(params);
            _BringClass.Verify(x => x.StartProcOld(params), Times.Once());
        }
```

Comment: Does your `_plugin` use the `_BringClassMock`? Could you please share with us the to-be-tested code as well?

Comment: I believe it doesn’t. I can’t unfortunately share the code Peter but ai can share some details. The class ClassWhereStartSitsIn has an empty constructor and takes no arguments. I believe that was your question right? I also have a feeling the issue is there. Because I am invoking a method Start() on that new class instance but setting it up on the mock. However, I am unable to make any changes to the codebase if that is the case and not sure how to get past this issue. Please tell me if I can share some other details. thank you for looking into it Peter

Comment: The problem with your provided example is that there are too much irrelevant stuff from the problem perspective (like `_connection`, `_mainC`, etc.) and too few about the actual problem itself. Could you please provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You got a point. Hope this is better.

Comment: What stands out to me is that when you're creating your `ClassWhereStartSitsIn` instance, you're not passing any of the mocked services into the constructor. This implies `ClassWhereStartSitsIn` is probably not using Dependency Injection to get its dependencies: it's using dependencies that it creates for itself, rather than the ones you give it. Moq doesn't control those dependencies, so it cannot mock their behaviors.